# Does anyone know what happened to the Parse.com documentation?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, documentation, mbaas

I'm building an app using Parse.com as my backend and am almost finished. I have been heavily reliant on the new Parse documentation throughout the process, but as of today all links to Parse documentation on all platforms simply link back to the new Parse open source website.

Specifically, I'm trying to find the iOS docs. Does anyone know where these can be accessed?

Example: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide redirects to https://parseplatform.github.io/

Any help would be much appreciated. This is a huge problem for me.

Comment: I think parse will be shut down by facebook soon. http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: Is http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/ not what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jonah thanks! No idea why but this morning this page couldn't be found, and redirected to the github page each time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, they changed stuff around.  You can see what they are up to in the docs repository: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/docs/commit/2ef1d0a5c7ac7079611b4d8afb66935a407739a3